# Largest Binary Search Tree in a Binary Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

So, the question is to find the largest sub-tree (the largest sub-tree is the node with maximum size) in a binary tree which is a BST.

I found the following website which enlists an algorithm.

http://amazoninterview.blogspot.in/2011/10/find-largest-binary-search-tree-in.html

Now upon repeated execution of the said code, I found that it gave correct results. However, I find (through dry runs and intuition) that instead of where it assigns (int the function getmaxbst(),

```
subtreemin = leftsubtreemin;
subtreemax = rightsubtreemax;
```

It should do the following

```
subtreemin = leftsubtreemax;
subtreemax = rightsubtreemin;
```

I tried executing the code with the above change and it provided the same and the correct result.

Can someone help me find out which of the above assignment is correct and why

Answer (score 0):

The original algorithm assignments are the correct ones.

'subtreemin' and 'subtreemax' are parameters of the 'getmaxbst' function and are passed by reference.  When these variables are assigned to, it is also changing the variable passed into the function which is either leftsubtree min/max or rightsubtree min/max. Since at the point of assignment it has already been decided that the subtrees are in fact BST's, the smallest value of the tree would be the smallest value of the left subtree (which is leftsubtreemin) and the largest value of the tree would be the largest value of the right subtree (rightsubtreemax).

I believe your mistake comes in thinking that 'subtreemin' and 'subtreemax' are being used as comparisons to determine if the subtree is in fact a BST, however this is done with different variables (namely leftsubtreemax and rightsubtreemin) at this point

```
if(root->data < leftsubtreemax ||
 root->data > rightsubtreemin){
return -1;
```

As to why both are producing similar and correct results I could not tell you without looking at the data, however it would seem that changing the assignments would produce the wrong result.  You might have gotten lucky with certain test cases.

Comment: Thank you, that did help clear stuff up. I would have upvoted you, but apparently I can't, since I don't have enough reputation.